# Compare memory pointers in Solidity

Tags: solidity, arrays, memory, data-types

Is there a way to compare pointers in Solidity?

I have two local variables:

```
uint256[] memory a = new uint256[](256);
uint256[] memory b = a;
```

If I try `a == b` I get this compiler error:

> TypeError: Operator `==` not compatible with types `uint256[] memory` and `uint256[] memory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to use the `eq` instruction in inline assembly:

```
uint256[] memory a = new uint256[](256);
uint256[] memory b = a;
bool aEqualsB;
assembly {
    aEqualsB := eq(a, b)
}
// aEqualsB now contains the value: true

b = new uint256[](256);
assembly {
    aEqualsB := eq(a, b)
}
// aEqualsB now contains the value: false
```

Comment: I will accept my own workaround as answer until there is a better way.

Comment: There is still no better way, as far as I'm aware.